# Galen javascript API. CSS selector for first child

Tags: galen

I am trying to write functional tests using Galen javascript API. I have to select first li of a ul.

```
this.menu = $page("Menu Bar", {
    menuItem: "ul.section li:first-child div"
});
```

It seems css selector first-child is wrong here.

I can do the same using xpath: `xpath: //ul[@class='section']//li[1]//div`

But I want to do using CSS selector. Please help

Answer (score 0):

---

Raised issue in github. It seems to be a galen problem.

https://github.com/galenframework/galen/issues/423

Will be fixed in the version 2.3